# Cant Initialize AutoMapper in Framework 4.7.1

Tags: c#, automapper

When Call Method `By<TModel>` in LoginService and try `ProjectTo<TModel>` give me exception Mapper not initialize. Call initialize with appropriate configuration......I try with `services.AddAutoMapper<>` like NetCore because there's work but in NetFramework dont find him. What is the most simple way to do in NetFramework. I read other old answer but think is too complex for me. Of course I can not use this Method with ProjectTo but...

Startup.cs

```
IServiceProvider service = ConfigureServices();
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile(service.GetService<DailyReporterProfiler>());

});

private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
{
    IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();
    services.AddTransient<ICommandInterpreter, CommandInterpreter>();
    services.AddTransient<IValidation, Validation>();

    #region Services
    services.AddTransient<ILoginService, LoginService>();
    #endregion
    services.AddDbContext<DailyReportContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.ConnectionString));

    services.AddSingleton<DailyReporterProfiler>();


    var result = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    return result;
}
```

Profiler.cs

```
public class DailyReporterProfiler : Profile
{
    public DailyReporterProfiler()
    {
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Account, AccountLoginDTO>().ReverseMap();
        });
    }
}
```

LoginService.cs

```
public class LoginService : ILoginService
{

    private DailyReportContext context;

    public LoginService(DailyReportContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public TModel ByUsername<TModel>(string username) => By<TModel>(u => u.Username == username)
        .SingleOrDefault();

    public string GetAccountStatus(string username)
    {
        var account = this.context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username).Status;

        var status = Enum.GetName(typeof(AccountStatus), account);

        return status;
    }

    public void ChangePassword(int userId, string password)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool CheckPassword(string username, string password)
    {
        var account = context.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);

        if (account.Password != password)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public bool Exists(string username) => ByUsername<Account>(username) != null;

    public IEnumerable<TModel> By<TModel>(Func<Account, bool> predicate)
    {
        return this.context.Accounts.Where(predicate).AsQueryable().ProjectTo<TModel>();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Static-and-Instance-API.html

Comment: Not help me bu thanks

Comment: Maybe you should start from a simple example and work your way up.